# How read the xmlstring into dataset in c#?

Tags: c#

Following xml string to read in to data set

```
<jxt>
    <success>True</success>
    <output>
        <jobs>
    <job>
        <id>1236563</id>
        <title>Electrical Engineering Manager  HV Testing & Condition Monitoring</title>
        <company>LM - Private Advertiser</company>
        <location>Sydney - City</location>
    </job>
</jobs>
    </output>
</jxt>
```

Comment: If you expect people to invest their time answering your question, YOU should invest some time in asking the question. Your question is broad and tells us nothing about which specific problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If you build an object model of identical structure, you can use this XML to deserialize into the objects you have defined.  Then you can just address the objects instead of the XML

Answer (score 0):

This will read xml using a xsd file.

```
ds_Dataset.ReadXmlSchema("scheme.xsd");
fs = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open);
ds_Dataset.ReadXml(fs);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: If you have to read XML from server then you can use WebRequest & WebResponse Class to Query the server & then simply in "DataSet.ReadXml" function pass the WebResponse.GetResponseStream() in that.